# watch on custom directive attribute not changing on parents scope change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive inside another custom directive and I want the sub directive to change when it's parent changes a scope value.

the html of the parent directive has a scope variable called childHeight and I have a function that sets it.

```
<button ng-on-click="setHeight(500)"> change the height </button>
<child-directive ctrl-height="childHeight"></child-directive>
```

the child directive has a watch on the ctrlHeight

```
scope: {
        ctrlHeight: '=?',
        ctrlWidth: '=?'
    },
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watchCollection(['ctrlHeight', 'ctrlWidth'], function() {
                scope.reSize(scope.ctrlWidth, scope.ctrlHeight);
        });
    }
```

When I change the scope variable in the setHeight

```
$scope.childHeight = 500;
```

how come the watch is not triggered.

I tried adding an $apply() or $digest both of which give me an error

Comment: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to watch both `ctrlHeight` and `ctrlWidth`, you could try something like this:
`scope.$watch('ctrlHeight + ctrlWidth', watcher);`
That way, everytime each of them changes, your `watcher` fn is triggered. Also `$apply()` will not work because you're already in Angular context.

Comment: I think the problem  is my collection the ctrlHeight are actually evaluated to strings not scope variables. so when I use 2 $watch one for width one for height it works.